# Delete text between <p> by javascript

Tags: javascript, html

I have the following HTML,two buttons and a paragraph code, and javascript, like the following:

```
// HTML
<input type="button" onclick="insert()" value="insert"/>
<input type="button" onclick="delete()" value="delete"/>
<p id='text'>
Line 1
Line 2
</p>

//javascript
function insert(){
  // ?
}

function delete(){
  // ?
}
```

When the user clicks the delete button, the Line 1 and Line 2 will be deleted.

When the user clicks the insert button, the Line 1 and Line 2 will be inserted.

The Line 1 and Line 2 will be only insert when they are not between the `<p id='text'>`.

Can anyone help me?

Comment: `delete` is a keyword. You may want to consider changing the name of that function.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

For `insert()`, how about

```
document.getElementById('text').innerHTML = 'Line 1\nLine 2';
```

and for `delete()`, how about

```
document.getElementById('text').innerHTML = '';
```

Please note that `delete` is a JavaScript keyword (and it's even actually implemented, which is more than I can say for the utterly excessive amount of reserved keywords that JavaScript has). You will need to name your `delete()` function something else.

Comment: `\n` will be interpreted as a literal character, I think you meant `<br>`.

Comment: I changed it *from* `<br>`, because the OP's question has a literal newline (that will be rendered as a space). My old answer was possibly what the OP could have meant (given 'Line 1' and 'Line 2') but my current answer is the more 'correct' one.

Answer (score 2):

With jQuery you can try:

```
$("#text").text('');
```

Comment: This is a good jQuery answer, but the OP did not mention that he is using a framework.

Comment: You're right... I'm just so used to the fact that everyone's using jQuery... It's almost the default choice for many.

Answer (score 1):

You could something quick and easy with jQuery... adding `id`s to your `buttons`.

```
$('#delete').click(function(){
    $('#text').html('');
})

$('#insert').click(function(){
    $('#text').html('Line 1 Line 2');
})
```

http://jsfiddle.net/jasongennaro/MTJxH/1/

Answer (score 1):

```
function insert() {
    var para = document.getElementById("text");
    if(para.innerHTML === "") {
        para.innerHTML = "line1<br />line2";
    }
}
function remove() {
    document.getElementById("text").innerHTML = "";
}
```

However, please notice that I've changed the name of your `delete` function, because `delete` is a JavaScript keyword, and can't be used as the name of a function.

Here's a [working example](http://jsfiddle.net/interdream/rkWDR/1/).

Answer (score 1):

```
function insert() {
    var p = document.getElementById('text');
    if (p.innerHTML == '') {
        p.innerHTML = 'Line 1<br />Line 2';
    }
} 
function delete() {
    document.getElementById('text').innerHTML = '';
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
function delete(){

        $('#text').html('');
    }

function insert(){
        if($('#text').text()=="")// add only if nothing inside
        {
        $('#text').html('Line 1 Line 2');
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
function delete()
{
    var delMe = document.getElementById('text');
    delMe.innerHTML = '';
}
function insert()
{
    var insMe = document.getElementById('text');
    insMe.innerHTML = "Line 1\r\nLine2";
}
```

Easy peasy.